A single POSIX-Extended regex to match all shortest substrings that start with “a”, end with “b” and do not contain any element of the set of strings
Given a string, is it possible to write a single POSIX-Extended regular expression to match all shortest substrings that start with a and end with b, but do not contain cb, cd or fg? I want to use such a regex with gensub, match or split functions (in gawk). For example,

string "0a3cbsbtacc12bbb": matching substring is "acc12b";
string "a4cdddbbb5": no matching substring;
string "1taa/b///fafgfgcb2abb": matching substrings are "a/b" and "ab".

The “mark the negative matches” approach (using characters that do not occur in the whole text) is not suitable in my situation: I am only interested in a single regular expression. So, if I use, for example, split("1taa/b///fafgfgcb2abb", arr, regex, seps), I expect seps[1] == "a/b" and seps[2] == "ab".
If it is not possible to write a suitable regex (or if any suitable regex is too inefficient performance-wise), I would be interested to know why.

Solvable using negative look-ahead (?!cb|cd|fg), but awk and POSIX/ERE do not support lookarounds.

please elaborate why marking negative match approach is not suitable in your case. Efficiency? Note that it is always possible to escape input strings so that unused characters become available for use. Are the strings multi-line? If not, newline is already available

@jhnc:  — because I could not find a generalized way to solve the problem, i.e. some fixed code that works with any input. If there is such a way, can you give a short description of the approach in the comments?

@EdMorton: I would definitely prefer a solution using a single POSIX ERE. Why? Because it allows to use gensub, match and split functions with this regex. Otherwise, one question becomes three questions (because those three functions solve three different problems).

@EdMorton: <you're asking about how to implement what you think is the solution to a problem rather than asking how to solve a problem> — there are three tasks: substitute, match and split. There exist the three corresponding functions to complete them. A single regex would allow to do this, so this regex is the solution (if it exists). So my question is definitely not an XY question...

If you actually just want to find all shortest strings on each line that start and end with strings and do not contain other strings then accept an answer to this question you asked (or don't if you feel you didn't get an answer) and then post a new question about that,, with a [mcve] including sample input/output demonstrating that.

@EdMorton: I already accepted the answer. Actually, now I am interested in a generalized algorithm (in the form of C-like pseudo-code) to construct the needed regex (given three inputs: the start substring, the set of disallowed substrings, the end substring), but this turns out to be a rather non-trivial problem and I do not even know where to ask...

I'm confused. Your question asks explicitly for a single regular expression. You even put it in italics. Now I see you accept an answer that does not give you a single regular expression. If only I had known that you were happy with other solutions, I would not have spent so much time on this :-(

@trincot: I accepted the answer when your answer was deleted. In any case, I explained the problem with the current version of your answer in my comment to it: since constructing the regex is so non-trivial, I need the pseudo-code to implement the solution that works in other situations.

Alright. Do you have your answer? Just to know whether an effort is still needed from my side.

@lyricallywicked you seem to be stuck in a very common mindset of trying to use a regexp to solve your problem instead of just trying to come up with the best solution to your problem which is why there's a quote/page about this - 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.'.

@trincot I appreciate the explanation of the dfa approach and I'm sure it will be helpful for other people who find it

@trincot: I have no idea whether an additional effort is needed from your side because I have concerns about the complexity/performance of the regex (and its generating function in the gawk language) for my combinations of three parameters (the start substring, the set of disallowed substrings, the end substring): I am afraid that the regex-based approach is not suitable for practical use. This possibility is what the last paragraph of the original question implied. [1/4]

@trincot: I have no idea what the regex will look like (and perform) in some situations (assuming that the start/end substrings have the maximum length of 64 characters, the set of disallowed substrings has the maximum size of 8, where each element has the maximum length of 4 characters). [2/4]

@trincot: The only thing I can say is that it would be interesting for me to see a gawk function (or the C-like pseudo-code that can be converted to a function in the gawk language) that, given three inputs (the start substring, the set of disallowed substrings, the end substring), outputs the POSIX-Extended regular expression to match all shortest substrings that start with the start substring and end with the end substring, but do not contain any of the disallowed substrings. [3/4]

@trincot: If the resulting regexes (and the corresponding generating algorithms in the gawk language) can have unacceptable complexity/performance, such a function will be only of theoretical interest for me, and I do not need it because I will not use it. [4/4]

@trincot:  — yes, but assuming that a and b are not two specific strings ("a" and "b"), but any two strings, and cb|cd|fg is not the specific set, but an example of a set. This is what I meant by "a generalized way to solve the problem" in my comment above. I admit, my mistake is that I have not mentioned this requirement explicitly in the original question...

Is acb a string "that start with a and end with b, but do not contain cb, cd or fg" or not? In other words are the a and b consumed as the start and end delimiters leaving just c to be tested against cb, cd, and fg, or are the delimiters to be included in the comparison against the unwanted strings?

@EdMorton: no, acb is not a string "that start with a and end with b, but do not contain cb, cd or fg". The entire string must be tested.

I am still fascinated by this question and might post a new or updated answer. Would abc be a match when a match must start  with ab and end with bc?

@trincot: <Would abc be a match when a match must start with ab and end with bc?> — the original question implies that the answer is “Yes”: the start/end strings can overlap. But I am also interested in the case when they cannot overlap, especially if this condition can improve the regex performance.

OK, because I progressed a lot on making a tool that takes the three inputs (prefix, list of negatives and suffix), and produces a regex as output. It takes the position that abc would represent a match. I am not too concerned about the performance of the regex, which does not mean it would be a short regex, but those are two distinct metrics.

more general solution:
Here is an awk function that takes a string s and three regex (rs,re,rx).
Output is a list of the indices, lengths and non-overlapping sub-strings of s such that:

rs matches at start (any other matches must overlap with re)
re matches at end (any other matches must overlap with rs)
rx does not match

awk '
function findshort (s,rs,re,rx,          pos,emax,elen,aftere,i,start, \
                                              q,trimmed,best,empty,ok) {
    # find, then loop over, re matches
    for (pos = 1; pos<=length(s) && match(substr(s,pos),re); pos += RSTART) {
        ++emax
        elen[emax] = RLENGTH
        aftere[emax] = (pos-1) + RSTART+RLENGTH + (!RLENGTH)
    }
    for (start = i = 1; i<=emax; ++i) {

        # trim right
        q = substr(s,start,(aftere[i]-start)) 

        # trim left
        for (ok = 0; pos = match(q,rs); q = substr(q,pos+1)) {

            # end correction for zero-length match
            empty = !RLENGTH && !elen[i]

            trimmed = substr(q,pos,(length(q)-(pos-1)-empty))

            if (length(trimmed)<elen[i]) break
            if (!match(trimmed,rx)) {
                ok = 1
                best = trimmed
            }
            if (!elen[i]) break
        }

        if (ok) {
            print aftere[i]-length(best)-empty, length(best), best

            # prune head
            start = aftere[i]  
        }
        # else extend right
    }
}
{
    # test scaffold
    printf "---- s:%s rs:%s re:%s rx:%s ----\n", $1,$2,$3,$4
    findshort($1,$2,$3,$4)
}
'

Running on input:
1taa/b///fafgfgcb2abb   a       b       cb|cd|fg
0a3cbsbtacc12bbb        a       b       cb|cd|fg
a4cdddbbb5              a       b       cb|cd|fg
aaabcbbaaaaaaefgbbbb    aa      bb      bc
abc                     abc     b       cb|cd|fg
abcb                    abc     b       cb|cd|fg
abcab                   abc     b       cb|cd|fg
00ab2bc11               ab      bc      $^
abcdef                  x*      [bc]    z
abcdef                  abcde   d*      z
abc                     .?      .?      .
abc                     .{0}    .{0}    z
abc                     .*      .*      z
abbbabaababab           ab+     b+a     z
abcd                    a?      b?      z
1aaab/ab0               a..     .ab     aa|aba
abaa                    a       ba      c

gives:
---- s:1taa/b///fafgfgcb2abb rs:a re:b rx:cb|cd|fg ----
4 3 a/b
19 2 ab
---- s:0a3cbsbtacc12bbb rs:a re:b rx:cb|cd|fg ----
9 6 acc12b
---- s:a4cdddbbb5 rs:a re:b rx:cb|cd|fg ----
---- s:aaabcbbaaaaaaefgbbbb rs:aa re:bb rx:bc ----
12 7 aaefgbb
---- s:abc rs:abc re:b rx:cb|cd|fg ----
---- s:abcb rs:abc re:b rx:cb|cd|fg ----
---- s:abcab rs:abc re:b rx:cb|cd|fg ----
1 5 abcab
---- s:00ab2bc11 rs:ab re:bc rx:$^ ----
3 5 ab2bc
---- s:abcdef rs:x* re:[bc] rx:z ----
2 1 b
3 1 c
---- s:abcdef rs:abcde re:d* rx:z ----
1 5 abcde
---- s:abc rs:.? re:.? rx:. ----
---- s:abc rs:.{0} re:.{0} rx:z ----
1 0 
2 0 
3 0 
---- s:abc rs:.* re:.* rx:z ----
1 3 abc
---- s:abbbabaababab rs:ab+ re:b+a rx:z ----
1 5 abbba
8 3 aba
---- s:abcd rs:a? re:b? rx:z ----
1 1 a
2 1 b
3 0 
4 0 
---- s:1aaab/ab0 rs:a.. re:.ab rx:aa|aba ----
4 5 ab/ab
---- s:abaa rs:a re:ba rx:c ----
1 3 aba

Basically, the function walks along the input string and loops doing:

extract leftmost shortest head of s that ends with an re
trim LHS to rightmost rs that starts at or before start of re
if rx does not match:

then:

print the trimmed string
delete head of s


else:

extend head right to end of next match for re





The results are produced by processing the input from left to right using a specific sequence of operations. Note that if processed in some other way by a different algorithm, different results are possible. For example:
input = abbbabaababab
rs = ab+
re = b+a
rx = z

could be legitimately split as any of:
<abbba> ba <aba> bab
abbb <aba> <aba> bab
abbb <aba> ab <aba> b


original accepted answer:
A demo of generic approach, as requested:
awk  '
    {
        printf "original: %s\n", $0

        # escape input to ensure availability of substrings for marking
        gsub(/=/,"=e")
        # now `/=[^e].*/` is guaranteed to not match 

        # mark negative matches
        gsub(/cb|cd|fg/,"=x&")
        printf "marked: %s\n", $0

        # split
        n = split($0, arr, /a([^ab=]|(=[^x]))*b/, seps)

        # unmark/unescape results
        gsub(/=x/,"", seps[0])
        gsub(/=e/,"", seps[0])
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            gsub(/=x/,"", arr[i])
            gsub(/=x/,"", seps[i])
            gsub(/=e/,"=", arr[i])
            gsub(/=e/,"=", seps[i])
        }

        printf "sep[0]: %s\n", seps[0]
        for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
            printf "pat[%i]: %s\n", i,arr[i]
            printf "sep[%i]: %s\n", i,seps[i]
        }

    }
' <<'EOD'
1taa/b///fafgfgcb2abb
EOD

giving:
original: 1taa/b///fafgfgcb2abb
marked: 1taa/b///fa=xfg=xfg=xcb2abb
sep[0]: 
pat[1]: 1ta
sep[1]: a/b
pat[2]: ///fafgfgcb2
sep[2]: ab
pat[3]: b
sep[3]: 

 (Buggy - finds leftmost shortest, not absolute shortest)
If a or b are strings rather than individual characters (e.g. aaaa,bbbb),
they need to be marked too. Then the split would look something like:
split($0, arr, /=xaaaa([^=]|(=[^x]))*=xbbbb/, seps)



Via DFA design and state elimination, I got to this regex:
a([^abcf]|c+[^abcdf]|c*f+(c+f+)*([^abcfg]|c+[^abcdf]))*(c*f+(c+f+)*)?b

First I will detail how you can design a DFA for this example, eliminate states and read-out the regex, and at the end I'll provide a runnable snippet that takes the three inputs (required prefix, a list of negatives, required suffix) and applies this algorithm to produce a regex.
DFA design
Here is the DFA that corresponds to the rules you have described:

Some notes:
I did not include the transitions that lead to a reject state. In particular:

from state  there are no transitions for the symbols b and d
for state  there is no transition for the symbol g
for states , , , and , there are no transitions for a
the start state has no transitions for symbols other than a
the accept state  has no transitions at all.

The transitions use regex syntax. In particular [^  ]. Further down these transitions will be extended with other regex syntax, such as * for zero or more repetitions, + for one or more repetitions, ?  for making a pattern optional, and | for alternatives (OR).
Transition and state elimination
The goal is to gradually remove loops and states from the DFA, extending remaining transitions with patterns that (potentially) match more than one symbol, so that eventually we get a DFA diagram with only a start and accept state, and with just one remaining transition between those two states, and which has the final regex.
First, we could remove the self-loops at states  and . All incoming transitions are affected:

Then we could remove state . This means that for each combination of incoming/outgoing transition, we need to add that sequence to the transition that replaces that pair (going directly from the source to the target, skipping ). There are two incoming and two outgoing transitions, so we have to do the job for 4 combinations:

Let's remove that loop that we introduced at :

Now we can remove state . It has one incoming and two outgoing transitions, so there are two combinations to replace:

Finally, we remove state , which means we have one remaining transition that incorporates the zero-or-more repetitions of the loop at :

And so we get the regex I mentioned at the top.
Tool to produce the regex
Here is a runnable JavaScript snippet that takes the prefix, negatives (each on a separate line) and suffix, then builds a DFA, converts it to a GDFA (using regexes as transition labels), performs state elimination to reduce that GDFA to just a start and an accept state, and outputs the achieved regex on screen:


function longestOverlap(a, b) {
    for (let len = Math.min(a.length, b.length); len > 0; len--) {
        if (b.startsWith(a.slice(-len))) return len;
    }
    return 0;
}

function normaliseNegatives(prefix, negatives, suffix) {
    // Remove negatives that have an occurrence of the prefix after their first character, unless it is inside an overlap with the suffix: then keep the negative
    negatives = negatives.filter(negative => {
        const i = negative.indexOf(prefix, 1);
        if (i < 0 || negative.length - longestOverlap(negative, suffix) <= i) return true;
    });
    // If any negative remains that still has the prefix in it after index 0, then truncate that negative at the end of that prefix occurrence:
    //    cf. test case #19
    negatives = negatives.map(negative => {
        const i = negative.indexOf(prefix, 1);
        return i < 0 ? negative : negative.slice(0, i + prefix.length);
    });
    // Remove negatives that include the suffix and that suffix isn't included in the overlap with the prefix:
    negatives = negatives.filter(negative => {
        const i = negative.slice(0, -1).lastIndexOf(suffix);
        if (i < 0 || i + suffix.length <= longestOverlap(prefix, negative)) return true;
    });
    // If any negative remains that still has the suffix in it before the last index, then start that negative at the start of that (last) occurrence:
    //    cf. test case #20
    negatives = negatives.map(negative => {
        const i = negative.slice(0, -1).lastIndexOf(suffix);
        return i <= 0 ? negative : negative.slice(i);
    });
    // Remove negatives that include another negative
    negatives = negatives.filter((negative, i) => 
        !negatives.some((other, j) => negative !== other ? negative.includes(other) : i < j)
    );
    return negatives;
}

class DFA {
    constructor(prefix, negatives, suffix) {
        const STATE_REJECT = "";
        const STATE_START  = "1";
        const STATE_LOOP   = "2";
        const STATE_ACCEPT = "3";

        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.negatives = negatives;
        this.suffix = suffix;
        // Start with a single state that is both the start state and accept state.
        this.states = {};
        this.defaults = {};
        // Special state identifiers:
        this.start = STATE_START;
        this.accept = STATE_ACCEPT;
        this.reject = STATE_REJECT;
        // Trivial cases:
        // If a negative is included in the required prefix or suffix, then nothing can match
        if (negatives.some(negative => prefix.includes(negative) || suffix.includes(negative))) {
            this.start = STATE_REJECT;
            return;
        }
        // If both prefix and suffix are empty, then the empty string will match
        if (prefix.length + suffix.length === 0) {
            this.start = STATE_ACCEPT;
            return;
        }
        // If by matching the prefix we also fulfill the suffix requirement, then the DFA simply tests for the prefix
        if (prefix.endsWith(suffix)) return this.addString(STATE_START, prefix, STATE_ACCEPT);
        // if by matching the suffix we also fulfill the prefix requirement, then the DFA simply tests for the suffix
        if (suffix.startsWith(prefix)) return this.addString(STATE_START, suffix, STATE_ACCEPT);
        // Remove redundant negatives or redundant affixes in them.
        negatives = normaliseNegatives(prefix, negatives, suffix);
        // Encode rejection of the negatives
        for (const negative of negatives) {
            this.addString(STATE_LOOP, negative, STATE_REJECT, true);
        }
        if (!prefix.includes(suffix)) {
            // Encode rejection of a prefix repetition
            this.addString(STATE_LOOP, prefix, STATE_REJECT, true);
        }
        // Encode the suffix 
        // A match of the suffix leads to an accept state:
        // First see if prefix is a substring of it, and in that case only allow looping until the prefix occurs
        let i = suffix.indexOf(prefix);
        this.addString(STATE_LOOP, suffix.slice(0, i > 0 ? i + prefix.length : suffix.length), STATE_ACCEPT, true);
        // Extend the suffix encoding with the irrevocable ending part (must match -- no more looping)
        if (i > 0) this.addString(STATE_LOOP, suffix, STATE_ACCEPT);
        // Encode the prefix, leading into the already built DFA
        this.addString(STATE_START, prefix, this.longestSuffixState(STATE_LOOP, prefix));
        // Add cross-overs for when one of these strings has a suffix that is a prefix of another.
        const loopStates = Object.keys(this.defaults).sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
        for (const stateId of loopStates) {
            const longest = this.longestSuffixState(STATE_LOOP, stateId.slice(STATE_LOOP.length + 1));
            // Add transitions to stateId when they don't exist there yet, but exist on the longest suffix state:
            this.states[stateId] = {...this.states[longest], ...this.states[stateId] };
        }
    }
    
    addString(group, s, finalStateId, addDefault=false) {
        if (!s) return;
        let stateId = group;
        for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            this.states[stateId] ??= { };
            if (addDefault) this.defaults[stateId] = group;
            stateId = this.states[stateId][s[i]] = stateId + s[i];
        }
        this.states[stateId.slice(0, -1)][s.at(-1)] = finalStateId ?? stateId;
    }

    longestSuffixState(group, needle) {
        for (let i = 0; i <= needle.length; i++) {
            const stateId = group + needle.slice(i);
            if (stateId in this.states) return stateId;
        }
    }    
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class RegexNode {
    constructor(args, operator="", callback) {
        this.level = 2*Array.isArray(args) + !!operator;
        const infix  = Array.isArray(args) ? operator : "";
        const suffix = Array.isArray(args) ? "" : operator;
        this.args = [].concat(args);
        this.args = this.args.flatMap(arg => arg.constructor === this.constructor ? arg.args : arg);
        this.args = callback ? callback(this.args) : this.args;
        const getRegex = (child) => child.level > this.level ? `(${child.regex})` : child.regex ?? child;
        this.regex = this.args.map(arg => getRegex?.(arg) ?? arg).join(infix) + suffix;
    }
    star() { return new RegexStar(this); }
    append(regex) { return new RegexSequence([this, regex]); }
    or(regex) { return new RegexAlternatives([this, regex]); }
}

class RegexChar extends RegexNode {
    constructor(ch) {
        super(ch, "");
        this.regex = ch.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
    }
}

class RegexCharExclude extends RegexNode {
    constructor(args) {
        super([...args].sort().join(""), "");
        this.regex = `[^${this.args[0].replace(/[-\]^\\]/g, "\\$&")}]`;
    }
}

class RegexStar extends RegexNode {
    constructor(arg) {
        super(arg, "*");
    }
}

class RegexSequence extends RegexNode {
    constructor(args) {
        super(args, "");
        if (this.args.length === 1) return this.args[0];
    }
}

class RegexAlternatives extends RegexNode {
    constructor(args) {
        super(args, "|");
        if (this.args.length === 1) return this.args[0];
    }
}

class GDFA extends DFA {
    constructor(prefix, negatives, suffix) {
        super(prefix, negatives, suffix); // Create DFA
        this.reverse = {};
        const gdfaStates = {};
        for (const stateId in this.states) {
            if (stateId === this.accept) continue; // This should not occur, but it doesn't hurt to test it
            const dfaState = this.states[stateId];
            const state = {};
            for (const ch in dfaState) {
                const targetId = dfaState[ch];
                if (targetId === this.reject) continue;
                state[targetId] = new RegexChar(ch);
                if (targetId === this.accept) continue;
                (this.reverse[targetId] ??= new Set).add(stateId);
            }
            if (stateId in this.defaults) {
                const targetId = this.defaults[stateId];
                state[targetId] = new RegexCharExclude(Object.keys(dfaState));
                (this.reverse[targetId] ??= new Set).add(stateId);
            }
            gdfaStates[stateId] = state;
        }
        this.states = gdfaStates; // Replace DFA with GDFA
        delete this.defaults;
    }
    
    reduce() {
        // Eliminate states in order of number of incoming*outgoing edges
        Object.entries(this.reverse).map(([stateId, set]) =>
            [stateId, set.size * Object.keys(this.states[stateId]).length]
        ).sort(([,a], [,b]) => a - b).forEach(([stateId, count]) =>
            this.eliminate(stateId)
        );
        // Return the regex that remains
        return this.start === this.accept ? "()"   // Boundary case: any empty string can match
             : this.start === this.reject ? "$a"   // Boundary case: nothing can match
             : this.states[this.start][this.accept].regex;        
    }
    
    eliminate(stateId) {
        if (this.reverse[stateId].has(stateId)) { // We have a loop
            const loop = this.states[stateId][stateId].star();
            for (const sourceId of this.reverse[stateId]) {
                if (sourceId === stateId) continue; // Skip the loop
                this.states[sourceId][stateId] = this.states[sourceId][stateId].append(loop);
            }
            this.reverse[stateId].delete(stateId);
            delete this.states[stateId][stateId];
        }
        for (const sourceId of this.reverse[stateId]) {
            for (const [targetId, {regex}] of Object.entries(this.states[stateId])) {
                const combined = this.states[sourceId][stateId].append(this.states[stateId][targetId]);
                this.states[sourceId][targetId] = 
                    targetId in this.states[sourceId] ? this.states[sourceId][targetId].or(combined) : combined;
                if (targetId in this.states) this.reverse[targetId].add(sourceId);
            }
        }
        for (const sourceId of this.reverse[stateId]) {
            delete this.states[sourceId][stateId];
        }
        for (const targetId in this.states[stateId]) {
            if (targetId in this.reverse) this.reverse[targetId].delete(stateId);
        }
        delete this.states[stateId];
        delete this.reverse[stateId];
    }
}

// I/O handling
const [inpPrefix, inpNegatives, inpSuffix, btnGo, output] = document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea, button, pre");
document.addEventListener("input", () => output.textContent = "");
btnGo.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const prefix = inpPrefix.value;
    const negatives = inpNegatives.value.match(/.+/g) ?? [];
    const suffix = inpSuffix.value;
    // Create a GDFA and reduce it to arive at a regex:
    const regex = (new GDFA(prefix, negatives, suffix)).reduce();
    output.textContent = regex;    
});
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { padding: 0; }
td { vertical-align: top }
textarea { height: 5em }
pre { white-space: wrap }
<table>
    <tr><th>Prefix:</th><th>Negatives:</th><th>Suffix:</th></tr>
    <tr><td><input value="a"></td><td><textarea>cb
cd
fg</textarea></td><td><input value="b"></td></tr>
</table>
<button>Generate regex</button><br>
Regex: <pre></pre>



This tool limits the regex operators to [^] (negative character classes), |, * and parentheses. I did not include any logic to reduce the size of the produced regex, which is a huge topic on its own. So, instead of c+, you'll see cc*, and instead of c?b, you'll see (cb|b), ...etc.
The produced regexes can get quite long, but in my tests they work.

Can you post the pseudo-code for the entire algorithm to generate the regex? The inputs are: 1. The start substring; 2. The set of disallowed substrings; 3. The end substring. The output is the regular expression.

That would be too broad to do. I hope my edit to the answer is enough to explain how I proceeded and got the result. See also How to convert finite automata to regular expressions?.

The regex itself seems to suit my needs (I tested it for a few inputs). But since I do not have the generating algorithm (as pseudo-code), I will be unable to construct regexes for other situations.

Quite impressive. Explains perfectly why me trying to come up with a 1-liner off the top of my head didn't end well...

@lyricallywicked you didn't ask for an algorithm to generate regexps, you asked for "a single POSIX-Extended regular expression to match all shortest substrings that start with a and end with b, but do not contain cb, cd or fg" which apparently this is (it looks impressive but you didn't provided adequate sample input/output to test against so we can't test whether or not it works in all cases). You should really ask a different question with a [mcve] if that's not what you actually wanted.

I added a runnable snippet that will produce a working regex for given inputs of prefix, negatives and suffix. I leave it to you to see if these regexes are workable for your use case, but it at least answers the question whether you can always find a regex for such requirements, and what the procedure is to get to such a regex.

@trincot: Thank you very much for the tool, this is very useful. I was trying to extract the algorithm to generate the regex only for a string that does not contain any element of the given set, but could not find how to apply it to the non-overlap case. So if it is possible, please consider the non-overlap case: match the shortest substring that starts with the given prefix, continues as a string (possibly the empty string) that does not contain any element of the given set of disallowed strings, then ends by the given suffix. Maybe this case can be added as an option in the snippet.

As you phrase it now, the disallowed strings would only apply to the middle part, not the prefix, nor the suffix. Is that correct?

@trincot: yes, that is correct.

So, for instance, if the input is prefix: a, negatives: [ab, ac], suffix: c, then ac, aac, abc and acc would all be valid inputs, but aacc would not. Correct?

@trincot: By “valid inputs” you mean matching strings? Yes, for your example ac, aac, abc and acc would all be matching strings, but aacc would not.

OK, understood. But that invalidates my whole answer, including the DFA. I think you should ask this as a new question, as its specifications are different.

Did you maybe miss my comment?

@trincot: no, I did not miss the comment, I have read it. You mean that I should post a question asking how to obtain the regex for the non-overlap case?

If you have trouble finding the solution, then that is what I suggest. This question was already quite broad as it is, and if now you have a question for different specifications, then that seems the best way to approach it.

@trincot: I have asked the separate question.

@trincot: I have a single remaining question which seems to be simpler than this one. All I need is, given a set N of disallowed strings, generate a POSIX-Extended regular expression R such that the entire input string S matches R if and only if any element of N does not occur in S. No need to find the prefix/suffix and extract substrings, just test the entire input: it matches or not. Would it be possible to modify the algorithm in your answer to answer this question? If yes, I can ask a separate question.

It would definitly need to be a separate question. But please make sure to describe your effort and what holds you back to make it work. The answer here should give you good ideas on making the algorithm.

It is possible to write a regex which enumerates all the possible ways to avoid the disallowed substrings:
([^cf]|c[^bd]|f[^g])*[cf]?$

This is quite clumsy in practice, though; it's probably better in most cases to refactor your thinking.
This only shows how to skip strings which are not cb or cd or fg. The [cf]?$ at the end should be just [cf]? if you embed it in a context where it needs to be followed by something, though if that something is b you want to exclude c too (because otherwise oops, you just allowed cb after all).
a([^cf]|c[^bd]|f[^g])*f?b

If you want to avoid having a or b in the skipped string, you'll need to add them to the disallowed set, too:
a([^abcf]|c[^bd]|f[^g])*f?b

Things will get somewhat more complicated if your real strings are longer than one or two characters; but this is what you actually asked about.

The given regex does not work. This code: echo '1taa/b///fafgfgcb2abb' | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 gawk -F '\\|' '{split($0, arr, /a([^cf]|c[^bd]|f[^g])*f?b/, seps); print(seps[1] ", " seps[2])}' — prints aa/b, abb instead of a/b, ab. This code: echo 'affgbcd' | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 gawk -F '\\|' '{split($0, arr, /a([^cf]|c[^bd]|f[^g])*f?b/, seps); print(seps[1])}' — prints affgb instead of the empty string.

* by definition matches the longest available substring. In PCRE you can say *? to switch to non-greedy matching, but in Awk you'd need to basically add ab to the disallowed character class [^cf] to get something similar. For your second example, I don't think your expectation is correct; it splits into the empty string and the remainder cd after the "separator".

Ultimately, these are exactly the types of reasons I'd try to avoid this approach.

<it splits into the empty string and the remainder cd after the "separator"> — if $0 is affgbcd, it should not split at all: there are no substrings that can be used as separators. So seps[1] must be printed as the empty string (because it does not exist), not affgb. But okay, it seems that it is not possible to have a suitable regex...

The a([^abcf]|c[^bd]|f[^g])*f?b regex finds a match in affgbcd, which it should not: echo 'affgbcd' | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 gawk -F '\\|' '{print(match($0, /a([^abcf]|c[^bd]|f[^g])*f?b/))}' prints 1 instead of 0.

supposedly EREs now allow +?, *?, ?? but it may be a while before implementations catch up

@jhnc FYI I asked the gawk and gnulib (as used by GNU awk, sed, grep, and bash) providers if/when they plan to support .*? etc. and the consistent answer was they don't have any plans to support it due to the complexity it introduces so "a while" may be an optimistic estimate :-). Gawk would only consider supporting it if gnulib did but even they they may choose not to support it. The GoAwk provider says their awk version supports it just because they happen to pick up another library that now supports it.
